# python3 Need some clarity on dictionary and loops

Tags: python-3.x

the python newb here... I've spent WAY too long trying to make sense of this so perhaps somone colud give me some clarity. Here is the code, I'm unsure how line 7 works specifically.

```
dict = {'a': 'one', 'b': 'two', 'c': 'three', 'd': 'four'}

letters = list(dict.keys())
print(letters)

for i in range(len(dict)):
    print(dict[letters[i]])  #what is this line doing????!!!
```

I'm not sure how to read the syntax. I thought it was going into my letters list and puliing out 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' yet I cannot print:

```
print(dict['a'])
```

how come I get error messages when trying to print this?

Comment: **Never** name a variable the same as a built-in. It may not be the source of your issue, but you can easily call it `d` instead of `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {'a': 'one', 'b': 'two', 'c': 'three', 'd': 'four'}

# convert the keys to a list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
letters = list(dict.keys())
print(letters)

# i is a number between 0 and the length of the dict, i.e. 4 (excluding 4)
for i in range(len(dict)):
    # letters[i] = find the letter i-th letter from list `letters`, i.e. i=1 -> 'b'
    # use that letter as the key and get its value, i.e. dict['b'] == 'two'
    print(dict[letters[i]])
```

Notes:

- As said in the comments, don't use a built-in name for variable names. Ideally, use a semantically clear name but for testing you'd often use 'd' for a dictionary, 'l' for a list and so on.
- Your code now prints the values of the dict. I hope you are aware that you can do it much easier.

Like this:

```
for value in d.values():
    print(value)
```

Comment: I think the OP would be more enlightened if shown how dictionaries work, rather than how to perform numeric-index based searches on its elements.

Comment: @jsbueno True, but I am simply asking their question. The only thing I did was explaining what their code does. Asking 'how do dictionaries work' would be too road a question, imo, and can be found anywhere on the web.